# HTML Email content overwrite preview text in email Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm working on a Django app that sends emails, here's my code:

```
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    message["From"] = formataddr(("CustomName", ""))
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["Text"] = "My tagline"

    template_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, f"templates/email/{template}")

    preview_text = "Welcome to site, complete your registration"
    html_text = render_to_string(template_path, context)
    preview = MIMEText(preview_text, 'plain')
    html = MIMEText(html_text, 'html')

    message.attach(preview)
    message.attach(html)

    self.server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, to_email, message.as_string())

    self.server.quit()
```

The HTML Django Template file is:

```
{% block html_body %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>This is a preview {{ name }}</title>
</head>

<h1>Welcome {{ name }}</h1>

</html>
{% endblock html_body %}
```

What I want to achieve is something like LikedIn, but the problem is that the preview text is overwritten by the html content.

Here's what I want:
[image]

And here's what the code do:
[image]

As you can see the highlighted text is not the "preview" but the html content.
Note that what I want to achieve is that the preview text will be visible only in the notification and not attached to the html email once opened in the app.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the title tag? `<title>Welcome {{ name }}</title>`

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code and it doesn't work. Thank you